# CSS Transition Issue: Transition-Transform Not Working as Expected on Inner Div Element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have applied transition-transform to the inner div but for some reason it's not working , the slider is working the div is moving because of the translateX but the transition isn't

for the context here is the code of transition-transform :

```
transition-property: transform;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 150ms;
```

and here is the calc-slider class:

```
   width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

here is the code :

```
<div className='relative w-[40%]  z-[90] hidden lg:flex  items-end overflow-x-hidden py-3 px-[30px]' >
                            <div key={slide} className={`flex calc-slider h-[62px] gap-3 transition-transform `} 
                                style={{transform:`translateX(calc(${slide} * -100%))`,
                                        
                                    }}
                            >
                                {slider.map(n=>{
                                    return (
                                        <div 
                                            onClick={()=>setIndex(n)} 
                                            className=' flex-shrink-0 calc-child-slider rounded-[10px] hover:scale-110 transition-all  duration-300 cursor-pointer border-transparent hover:border-white border-[1px]' 
                                        >
                                            <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${frontMovies[n].backdrop_path}`} alt="" className={`h-full w-full rounded-[10px]`} />
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
</div>
```